# Resolve the database relationship cycle

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, database-relations

In the database I have a model of kind:
[image]

The customer can either rent a car or rent out a car. As you see Car has OwnerID - customer who owns a car but at the same time customer can also rent a car from another owner so that in Order table he appears as User.
So how can I change the model to avoid such cycles and is it even possible?

Comment: Can a customer rent from your business, as opposed to renting from a car owner? Is every customer required to be a car owner?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: So a user is a customer who is a renter? You couldn't call a user a renter or a renter a user? PS What is wrong with cycles & what is a cycle & what are the cycles here? (Your arrows  do not form a directed cycle.)

Comment: So a user is a customer who is a renter? You couldn't call a user a renter or a renter a user? PS What is wrong with cycles & what is a cycle & what are the cycles here? (Your arrows do not form a directed cycle.) PS There is nothing wrong with this design given your specification (with reasonable assumptions) & the actual problem is that you have wrong expectations/notions. Tell us what you are reasoning from what assumptions. You might have been right, so we would have something to validate; but you happen to be mistaken, so we will debunk it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider identifying (storing in tables)

- who the owners are and what they own, and
- who the customers are.

.

```
create table persons (
  -- I prefer "people". YMMV.
  person_id integer primary key,
  person_name varchar(25) not null
  -- Other columns go here.
);

create table cars (
  -- VIN might be a better choice.
  car_id integer primary key
  -- Other columns go here.
);

create table car_owners (
  -- Only car owners known to us can rent out a car.
  car_id integer not null
    references cars(car_id),
  owner_id integer not null
    references persons (person_id),
  primary key (car_id, owner_id)
  -- Other columns go here.
);

create table customers (
  -- Any person can rent a car. (But some persons are not customers.)
  customer_id integer primary key  
    references persons (person_id)
  -- Other columns go here.
);

create table rentals (
  customer_id integer not null
    references customers (customer_id),
  car_id integer not null,
  owner_id integer not null,
  primary key (customer_id, car_id, owner_id),

  -- Don't rent a car unless we know who the owner is.
  foreign key (car_id, owner_id)                  
    references car_owners (car_id, owner_id)

  -- Other columns go here.
);
```

Comment: This does not address the question since the question design is subsumed by this design. There's nothing wrong with the question design per se & giving a more complex design does not help & you don't address their question & its misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I think it is better to have two separate profile's for owner(person who rents out the car) and tenant(person who takes for the car for rent) and have separate logins

```
User      Owner      Tenant     Order
------    ------     -------    -------    
id        owner_id   tenant_id  owner_id 
email     user_id    user_id    tenant_id 
                                car_id
```

Hope this helps you!